# Extra "..." added to the conversation drivers during on-device testing for Bixby

Tags: bixby

There is an extra "..." added to the conversation drivers when testing the capsule on a testing device using Private Submissions, can we get rid of this? On clicking on this button nothing happens. This does not appear on the IDE but on the testing it on the real device it comes up.

[image: More conversation drivers button]

Answer (score 1):

That `...` link goes to the capsule's about page (where you can see the hints, manage data preferences, etc.) The page only works for capsule that have been released to the marketplace.

To see this page for yourself, try another capsule, such as Weather.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Just curios to know if it is possible to remove this? We may not want to redirect the user to the about page for all the queries.

Comment: It's only there when you have conversation drivers. But short of not having conversation drivers - No.

Comment: @AbhishekMittal a feature request has been submitted based on your input